# Error in devstack script. nova-api did not start?

Tags: python, openstack, openstack-nova

I have installed openstack on Ubuntu 12.04 single node using devstack. Now, it was running smoothly till yesterday. When i ran ./stack.sh today, it showed an error

./stack.sh:672 nova-api did not start

I have python-paste and python-pastedeploy installed. How to fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

check out for errors in nova api screen 
run this command to open screens

`screen -x stack`

open n-api screen ususally ( Ctrl + A + 5 ). 
Check for errors and then restart Nova API with this command.

```
cd /opt/stack/nova && /usr/local/bin/nova-api & echo $! >/opt/stack/status/stack/n-api.pid; fg || echo "n-api failed to start" | tee "/opt/stack/status/stack/n-api.failure"
```

Answer (score 0):

General rule of thumb for devstack.

Always unstack.sh before re-running stack.sh or pulling from repositories and re-running stack.sh

Comment: Yeah, I did that and unfortunately it didn't work. So, I just deleted the VM, launched it again and set up devstack. It's working fine as of now. Though, I am not sure, when it's gonna crash again!

Comment: It's an active dev environment.  Occasionally someone breaks the build =/  Happens less often now.  Usually gets corrected fairly quickly.  You might consider working inside of an LXC rather than a VM... or keeping a virgin qcow to reset to and build from.