# Devstack installation error(Nova-api did not start)

Tags: python, openstack

Plase help .Stuck here

```
+ screen -S stack -p n-api -X stuff 'cd /opt/stack/nova && /opt/stack/nova/bin/nova-api & echo $! 
>/opt/stack/stat's/stack/n-api.pid; fg || echo "n-api failed to start" | tee "/opt/stack/status/stack/n-api.failure"
./stack.sh:1085:start_nova_api
/home/devstack/lib/nova:610:die
[ERROR] /home/devstack/lib/nova:610 nova-api did not start
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079919/error-in-devstack-script-nova-api-did-not-start?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and I solved it by removing the nova folder.

sudo rm -rf /opt/stack/nova.

If that's not working, also try,

sudo apt-get purge python-paste python-pastedeploy
sudo apt-get install python-paste python-pastedeploy